# Does Samsung Galaxy S Indian ROM (latest DDJP6) has Bengali support?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, languages

I've read in several forums that *Indian version* of **Samsung Galaxy S** (I9000) supports Hindi language. Some of them mentioned it should support Bengali/Bangla also.

Can anyone here confirm that-
1) The latest Froyo firmware DDJP6 for Samsung Galaxy S supports Bengali? I don't need IME/a Bengali keyboard, just ability to render Bengali websites (like, [Bengali Wikipedia](http://bn.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E0%A6%AA%E0%A7%8D%E0%A6%B0%E0%A6%A7%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%A8_%E0%A6%AA%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%A4%E0%A6%BE)) properly would be great.

2) If it doesn't support Bengali out of the box, does installing a Bengali fallback font serve the purpose? Please note that merely showing Bengali characters won't help. As this is a *complex language*, a proper shaper must be present in firmware to render kar/matra and conjuncts correctly.

---

**Update**: I have recently bought a Samsung Galaxy series device. Yes, its Indian ROM has Bangla shaper, only replacing `DroidSansFallback.ttf` with a Bangla font will do.

Comment: I wonder if you could try it out using the Android Emulator within the SDK ?

Comment: Android doesn't support Bengali out of the box, but some vendor specific firmwares do (Like Sony Ericsson Xperia X10i Indian). Is it possible to setup AVD using exactly the Indian firmware of Galaxy S?

Comment: I am interested to know if it supports tamil language. Did anyone find a link which has the list of languages supported?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have latest official firmware sgs.
I can see hindi website, but no bangla.....at all!!!

u can use the procedure to see bangla fonts by http://suhreed.wordpress.com/2011/04/27/how-to-install-bangla-font-on-samsung-galaxy-tab/
or
http://blog.mehedi.me/bangla-font-on-android/

thanking you

Answer (score 2):

Here's a workaround using Opera Mini.

Download and install Opera Mini (OM). Try accessing a site like the one cited above - http://bn.wikipedia.org

If it doesn't work out of the box, do the following:

In the address bar, type **opera:config**
Navigate to the option **Use bitmap fonts for complex scripts** and set it to YES

The fonts and script lettering should now be visible, albeit as images instead of text. That'll make content visible, but unlike text non-selectable.

Comment: Oh! Thank you. I knew about this Opera Mini trick. That's actually the last place to go. You not only loose selectable text, the huge flexibility (including javascript support) of default browser is gone and transferring image instead of text increases data volume. iOS 4 supports complex scripts, it is a shame that all androids don't. (Or, do they? How?)