# Need fonts of a different language to show up on android or atleast Instapaper

Tags: languages, localization, fonts, instapaper

My family is residing in USA and we are from India. Now my mom gets super bored at home! And loves to read the regional online newspaper and magazines from India on the Internet; problem is she doesn't know how to use a computer! Me or my dad has to sit with her and click links for her, I have never heard anyone say a simple back in a browser in so many ways!.

Interestingly, she didn't have a hard time in using my dad's iPhone 4, in which he managed to lose!

I already own a Asus Transformer 300t and I tried to *instapaper* the websites she visits [Gujrat Samachar Sunday Special](http://www.gujaratsamachar.com/20100905/purti/ravipurti/ravihome.html) this she doesnt miss at any chance.

Problem is, those turn up beautifully on the desktop/webapp but the fonts aren't rendered properly on my tablet or any Android device, before I go ahead and get a Nexus 7 or Galaxy Tab 7, can I have this font show up on Android or at least, instapaper.

All I need to do is *instapaper* every article when I come home in evening (morning time in India, meaning the newspaper just came out), so that she can read it next day and as a trial run on my tablet!,

Also, those websites, at least the one mentioned above, don't implement RSS feeds or else I could have had my Calibre auto generate/fetch daily news and make an e-book every day and download it on the tab. But I also don't know if those fonts will be detected on Kindle app or any app for that matter!

I know I can try having it outputted as PDF but teaching her to go to PDF and then browse; that's too much for me to teach! The instapaper works smoothly, open instapaper, read headlines, tap that and read/scroll/read , press back next article... plus I still got to download that PDF for her to the tablet

Also reason I'm saying Instapaper often is cause only that will detect the actual title of article

Some screenshots: for following [Article](http://www.gujaratsamachar.com/20130106/purti/ravipurti/chingari.html)
Android Apps:

1. [Instapaper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QswnN.png)
2. [Readability](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOCgq.png)
3. [Pocket](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZpSb.png)

Web Version:

1. [Instapaper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvIe2.png)
2. [Readability](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntXUi.png)
3. [Pocket](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hxfux.png)

[Android Web Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/glQaU.png)

Comment: what device of tablet are you referring to?

Comment: Tf300t or Asus Transformer Pad that i currently own, I might get her a nexus 7

Comment: The reason it works on desktop/webapp is because the desktop has the necessary fonts for rendering! What you're asking here, is to add/install a font for usage, PDF's can embed fonts so that the viewer will use it for rendering on screen... just saying.

Comment: Have you seen http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4213/how-can-install-a-hindi-font-in-android-2-1 ? Also: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9021/does-samsung-galaxy-s-indian-rom-latest-ddjp6-has-bengali-support and http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5423/is-there-a-browser-that-will-display-armenian-letters

Comment: okay lemme check

Comment: Any progress made? Did you solve your issue? Feedback welcome -- you may also answer your own question ;)